# O que significa uma tabela com OCCURS 0 em ABAP?

Tags: erp, abap

Estou iniciando no mundo SAP e encontrei uma tabela interna declarada da seguinte forma:

```
DATA: it_buscar TYPE ty_ztabela OCCURS 0 .
```

O que esse **OCCURS 0** siginifica?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Occurs 0** Especifica quantas linhas a tabela pode ter, quando colocado o zero é que pode ter quantas linhas for necessário.

Comment: Shooow é isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**Occurs 0** serve para declarar uma tabela, sem informar a quantidade de memória que será alocada inicialmente.

Se você declarar **Occurs 10**, será alocado inicialmente já o espaço de 10 linhas para sua tabela interna. Não significa que apenas 10 linhas possam ser inseridas. Se o seu programa precisar inserir a 11ª linha, uma nova alocação será realizada automaticamente.

A informação sobre alocação ainda existe e agora deve ser feita com a instrução **INITIAL SIZE**.

Exemplo:

```
DATA: gt_mara TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF mara INITIAL SIZE 10.
```

Utilizar **INITIAL SIZE** ou **Occurs 0** é útil quanto você tiver uma tabela dentro de uma outra tabela e quiser evitar a alocação de espaço desnecessário.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A resposta do Eduardo esta correta, mas é uma forma obsoleta, sempre que for criar uma tabela é melhor usar TYPE TABLE OF 'aqui sua tabela'